# What happens to reputation when someone flags a post?

Tags: discussion, reputation, flags, comment-flags, helpful-flags

I know flagging a post is the way to let moderators know something is wrong, but does this impact reputation at all?  If I flag an offensive post, for example, does the user who made the post loose any reputation, or are there any negative consequences to the offender?  Do I gain reputation from raising helpful flags?

Comment: In short: you don't gain any reputation whatsoever from flags. Authors of offensive or spam posts lose 100 reputation only if the post got 6 such flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no gain/loss of reputation points from a single flag anywhere on the Stack Exchange network, for either the flagger or the flaggee.

As noted in the comments, if a post gets 6 spam or offensive flags, its author will lose 100 points, but that's the only reputation effect.

Raising flags impacts only four things.

1. Raising the daily cap on the number of flags you can raise on a given site.

   - Up to a maximum of 100 flags/day on a given site.
2. Your personal flagging statistics.

   - Not rep points, but it can be kind of addictive to see that number inch up.  I'm almost at 2,000 on Server Fault... just 11 more to go!
   - If you ever run in a moderator election, your flagging history is a prominent statistic that many people will use to determine your mod-worthiness.
3. Obtaining the flag-related badges.

   - Citizen Patrol, Deputy and Marshall
4. Review queues.

   - Flagging a post as `very low quality`, or `not an answer`, for example, will put it into the `Low Quality` queue for other users to review.

Comment: "There is no gain/loss of reputation points from a single flag" - that is not true. Single spam/offensive flag cause automatic downvote, cast by Community. So such a flag has -2 instant rep impact. (And yes, it allows "double downvote" by same user.)